# New application for every activity Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I dont understand why my application creates every activity as an application?
[image: applications]

Сould this be a configuration error?
Need help!

Comment: Post your manifest.The error could be there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove this from other Activity than MainActivity from AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"  />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't set a launcher Activity in your Manifest like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

See in your manifest. I think you simply copy pasted the activity tag for every activity by changing the activity name .Remove launcher attribute from it.